# Supplying 'iteration directions' to a method

Tags: python, list, methods, iteration

First of all, I'm sorry that I couldn’t think about a more accurate title for my question.

I have a list of tuples, the first value is the data I’m interested in, while the second one tells me whether it is relevant. I have a starting position and want to move from this in both directions until a uninteresting value occurs. As you can see both while loops are quite symmetric. I want to write a method to which I can supply a ‘direction’, to avoid code duplication. 
A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
l = [("0", "T"), ("1", "F"), ("2", "T"), ("3", "T"), 
("4", "T"), ("5", "T"), ("6", "F"), ("7", "T")]

out =[]
start = 3
interesting = set("T")

i = start
current_value, current_tag = l[i]
while current_tag in interesting and i>= 0:
    out.append(current_value)
    i -= 1
    if i >= 0:
        current_value, current_tag = l[i]

i = start + 1
current_value, current_tag = l[i]
while current_tag in interesting and i < len(l):
    out.append(current_value)
    i += 1
    if i < len(l):
        current_value, current_tag = l[i]
```

I know this doesn’t look so bad, but in my original use case the several methods get applied to the data and I will need to reuse these individually.

Thank you in advance for you time.

Comment: First of all why not True / False in place of "T" / "F" which are stings.
Secondly could you provide an example of input and output of what you want to do?

Comment: I tryied to simplify my example as much as possible. In the actual use case the number of possible tags is close to 100 and I'm interested in 7 of them. I thought adding additional tags only obscures the actuall problem of changing the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the idea; adjust to taste.

```
def scan(data, start, step):
    i = start
    result = []
    while 0 <= i < len(data):
        element = data[i]
        if element % 5 == 0:  # Our 'uninteresting' condition
            break
        result.append(element)
        i += step
    return result


>>> scan(range(10), 3, 1)
[3, 4]  # 5 stopped us
>>> scan(range(10), 7, -1)
[7, 6]  # 5 stopped us again
```

Comment: Oh my god, now that I see it it is so obvious... Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that the two while loops can be simplified as one. I wrote it into a function:

```
def scan(l, interesting):
   out = []
   i = 0
   current_value, current_tag = l[i]
   while current_tag in interesting and i < len(l):
       out.append(current_value)
       i += 1
       current_value, current_tag = l[i]
   return out
```

This is essentially the forward version from above. Now, your problem is how to apply this on the reverse direction right? The answer to that is **to feed the required list in reversed order** which can be easily done in python using `l[start:0:-1]` and then run `scan` function on the remaining list directly.

Hence, the final solution would then be:

```
scan(l[start:0:-1]) + scan(l[start+1:])
```

Which then gives: `['3', '2', '4', '5']`, that is exactly the same with the output of your code above.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: It looks like your `scan` can be replaced by `filter` or a list comprehension.

Comment: @9000, you are right. I can actually rewrite the code in fewer lines. I intentionally decided to keep the code closer to the one in the problem and let the author refactor his/her code later on..